# how can I test scope with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, scope

These are some code of my Cashout model.I can test all model with rspec but I don't know how can I test these scopes.

**cashout.rb**

```
class Cashout < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :partner

scope :add_virtual_columns, select(
    "cashouts.*,
    ( SELECT SUM(c.amount) FROM cashouts c WHERE c.partner_id = cashouts.partner_id) as total_paid_amount,
    (
      (
      CASE
        WHEN (SELECT partner_type FROM partners WHERE cashouts.partner_id = partners.id) = 'administrator'
        THEN
          (
            CASE 
                WHEN ( SELECT SUM(cr.partner_profit) FROM contact_records cr WHERE cr.partner_id in (SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id in (SELECT company_id FROM partners WHERE id = cashouts.partner_id))) IS NULL
                THEN 0 
                ELSE ( SELECT SUM(cr.partner_profit + cr.company_profit) FROM contact_records cr WHERE cr.partner_id in (SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id in (SELECT company_id FROM partners WHERE id = cashouts.partner_id)))
            END
            )
        ELSE
          (
          CASE 
            WHEN ( SELECT SUM(cr.partner_profit) FROM contact_records cr WHERE cr.partner_id = cashouts.partner_id) IS NULL
            THEN 0 
            ELSE ( SELECT SUM(cr.partner_profit) FROM contact_records cr WHERE cr.partner_id = cashouts.partner_id)
          END
          )
      END
      )
      -
      ( SELECT SUM(c.amount) FROM cashouts c WHERE c.partner_id = cashouts.partner_id)
    ) as unpaid_amount"
  ).group('cashouts.id')
  scope :sort_by_total_paid_amount_asc, order("total_paid_amount ASC")
  scope :sort_by_total_paid_amount_desc, order("total_paid_amount DESC")
  scope :sort_by_unpaid_amount_asc, order("unpaid_amount ASC")
  scope :sort_by_unpaid_amount_desc, order("unpaid_amount DESC")
end
```

Do you know how can I test these scopes with rspec and factorygirl?

Answer (score 3):

Guessing roughly at your schema, you first have to set up factories for all the pieces and their associations. Here's a rough outline. You'll have to fill in their other attributes with valid values.

[Faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) is extremely useful for filling in valid data.

```
factory :company do
end

factory :partner do
  company
end

factory :contact_record do
  partner
end

factory :cashout do
  partner
  total_paid_amount { Faker::Number.digit }
end
```

Testing the sorting scopes are easy. Make an Array of cashouts with different amounts, sort them as you expect, and see if you get that back.

Our factories are already set up to give us cashouts with random total_paid_amounts. We just need to create a list of them.

```
context 'with cashouts' do
  let(:cashouts) {
    create_list(:cashout, 3)
  }

  describe '.sort_by_total_paid_amount_asc' do
    it 'sorts by total_paid_amount in ascending order' do
      expect(
        Cashout.sort_by_total_paid_amount_asc.to_a
      ).to eq cashouts.sort_by(&:total_amount_paid)
    end
  end

  describe '.sort_by_total_paid_amount_desc' do
    it 'sorts by total_paid_amount in descending order' do
      expect(
        Cashout.sort_by_total_paid_amount_desc.to_a
      ).to eq cashouts.sort_by(&:total_amount_paid).reverse
    end
  end
end
```

I avoided generating the cashouts in order. This would put them in the table already in order and their default sorting might match our expectations.

Though I question the value of such literally named and trivial scopes. They're easily written as `Cashout.order(total_paid_amount: :asc)` which requires no testing.

---

Testing `add_virtual_columns`... `add_virtual_columns` is a poor name. It seems like it's adding a single column, `unpaid_amount`. I'd call it `with_unpaid_amount`.

`with_unpaid_amount` is more complicated because it's pretty complicated and requires more test data. Fortunately we have our relationships set up in our factories.

First, we set up our objects so they all share the same partner. There's several ways to do this, but I've chosen to generate the partner and pass it around. This makes it easier to modify each object to test different scenarios.

```
describe '.with_unpaid_amount' do
  let(:partner) {
    create(:partner)
  }
  let(:company) {
    create(:company, partner: partner)
  }
  let(:cashout) {
    create(:cashout, partner: partner)
  }
  let(:contact_record) {
    create(:contact_record, partner: partner)
  }
```

With this in place you can now alter the objects to test different scenarios. For example, what if a partner is an administrator?

```
  context 'when the partner is an administrator' do
    before {
      partner.update!(partner_type: 'administrator')
    }

    it '...'    
  end
```

And so on from there.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to create some test data and comparing the scope results to what you expect to happen. FactoryGirl can help you create the base `Cashout` models, on which you could override the `amount` and `partner_id`, and then generate corresponding `Partner` and `ContactRecord` models.

For the latter scopes, you could do something like

```
Cashout.sort_by_total_paid_amount_asc.to_sql.should == \ 
Cashout.order('total_paid_amount ASC').to_sql
```

Comment: I gave this a down vote. Testing the raw SQL is glass-box testing of the specific implementation of the scope; if the implementation changes even slightly the test breaks defeating the only reason to put such a simple query in a scope at all. Worse, it doesn't check that the scope does its job: sorting.